# Set AJAX dataType using Vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using some AJAX like this:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    data = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

The xmlhttp.responseXML is returned in XML, so it's a javascript object. However, I would like it in raw string format. Something akin to setting `dataType: "text"` in jQuery's `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `responseText` instead of `responseXML`

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com",false);
xmlhttp.send();
data = xmlhttp.responseText;
```